# Mass update case Status - Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I am looking for a way to mass update case Status and leave a success message or failure message with failed case ID.
I currently have validation rules and triggers for update or cases. But I need to keep show  at least the first failed case ID in the error message.

Is there a way to put a variable in the validation rule error message? Or its explicitly string?

I currently use a validation rule but I cant show the failed case in my error message because I cant put a variable in the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this Link it might help you http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003IleFEAS

You need to use a before trigger in this case and compare the list of selected cases before and after the update.

Or you can create a custom button and add it to the page and run the desired javascript to check what changed before and after.

something like this :

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/13.0/connection.js")} 

var idArray = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Case)}; 
var err = []; 
var caseObj; 

for (i=0; i< idArray.length ; i++){ 
    caseObj = new sforce.SObject("Case"); 
    caseObj.Id = idArray[i]; 
    caseObj.Status = *** //change status here;
    var result = sforce.connection.update([caseObj]); 

    if (result[0].success=='false') { 
        err.push("\n"+result[0].errors.message + " Case ID "+idArray[i]); 
    } 

} 

if(err.length >0) 
{     
    alert(" The following cases have failed to change status: \n\n" +err); 
} 

location.reload(true);
```